# set up default element decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-decorators

i wrote own decorator in the app path like "library/myLib/Form/Decorator/Lalala.php"

now suppose to use it like `$element->addDecorator('Lalala');`
but get error:

> Plugin by name 'Filechoose' was not found in the registry; used paths:
>   Zend_Form_Decorator_: Zend/Form/Decorator/

how to set up default element decorator paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your decorator class `myLib_Form_Decorator_Lalala` is stored in file `library/myLib/Form/Decorator/Lalala.php`, then we can do it as follows:

At the form level:

```
$form->addElementPrefixPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/myLib/Form/Decorator', 'myLib_Form_Decorator_', Zend_Form::DECORATOR);
```

At the element level:

```
$elt->addPrefixPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/myLib/Form/Decorator', 'myLib_Form_Decorator_', Zend_Form::DECORATOR);
```

Comment: and i must do that for every time? is there any way to put that into config or to bootstrap?

Comment: I've never found a way to do it at Bootstrap. So what I usually do is create a base class for my forms and put this into the constructor (don't forget the call to the `parent::__construct()`, which ultimately calls `init()` where typically your element enumeration exists). Then all my child forms extending this one have the element prefix paths "automatically" set.

Comment: then ok. =( hope to see "yes yes u can" =)